# Danish letters in AT command

Tags: sms, at-command, modem

I am trying to get my SMS gateway to send SMS using AT commands. I am connecting via SSH i a command prompt. I am a beginner to this, so please bear over with me.
The following lines work:

```
DEV=/dev/ttyACM1
DESTNUM="PHONENUMER"
SMS="Test SMS from ø"
echo -e "ATZ\r" >$DEV
echo -e "AT+CMGF=1\r" >$DEV
echo -e "AT+CMGS=\"$DESTNUM\"\r" >$DEV
echo -e "$SMS\x1A" >$DEV
```

So the above sends the sms correctly, but it does not include the dansih letter "ø". Usually this is included in UTF-8.

How do I get my code working with the danish characters? Any ideas?

Comment: Try `SMS="Test SMS from \x0C"`. If it works I'll write an answer explaining it.

Comment: That works ! :-)
So this encoding - Can I find for the other dansih letters? I mean æ and å

Comment: Never mind. Found it myself.
How do I add a "sleep" line to this code?

Comment: I was writing an answer for you...be patient! PS: [sleep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, short messages are sent using [GSM aplhabet (03.38)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38), defined by **3GPP TS 23.038**. This setting can be changed by issuing `AT+CSMP` command (Set Text Mode Parameters - I'll not examine it in depth in this answer).

More specifically, [7-bits aplhabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38#GSM_7-bit_default_alphabet_and_extension_table_of_3GPP_TS_23.038_/_GSM_03.38) is used, so that the device can encode 8 characters in 7 bytes (8x7=56), saving "precious space" to send some more information.

This alphabet is a clever derivation from 7-bit ASCII. A set of codes used in ASCII for "useless" characters (especially control characters) are instead used to add specific characters from alphabet such as Danish:

| Danish Character | GSM 03.38 code |
| --- | --- |
| Ø | `\x0B` |
| ø | `\x0C` |
| Å | `\x0D` |
| å | `\x0F` |
| Æ | `\x1C` |
| æ | `\x1D` |

For this reason, all you need is to write a special routine converting specific Danish characters into the corresponding escape code.